# Block only moves once on KEYDOWN (Python3.6 - Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

My name is Jeremy and I am learning Python. I am a beginner and I just started a couple of days ago. 
I am making a simple game in Python, and I would like my block/player to move continuously while the respective arrow key is held down. As of now, it only moves once when pressing down the arrow keys. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the code I've written:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


blockImg = pygame.image.load('blockpic.png')

def block(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(blockImg, (x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

x_change = 0
y_change = 0
crashed = False

while not crashed:

             for event in pygame.event.get():
                 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                     crashed = True

                 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            x_change = -10
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            x_change = 10
                        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            y_change = -10
                        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                            y_change = 10

                 if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            x_change = 0 
                        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            y_change = 0




                 x += x_change       
                 y += y_change
                 gameDisplay.fill(white)
                 block(x,y)
                 pygame.display.update()
                 clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You're only moving when you get an event.

Comment: Could you please suggest some kind of change in the code that could fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Think about what you want the object to do while you wait for the KEYUP event to be triggered.

Comment: I'm not really sure what else I need to change. Sorry for my lack of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not indented correctly. The line `x += x_change` and the five lines beneath are inside of the event loop, so they get executed once per event in the event queue. Just dedent these lines to fix the program.

```
while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = 0

    # The following lines should be executed once per frame not
    # once per event in the event queue.
    x += x_change
    y += y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    block(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So x += x_change and the five lines beneath it should be dedented all the way so that they are in line with while not crashed:?

I tried doing that, and when I ran it, the window was black and neither the white background nor the block appeared.

Comment: No, they should be in the while loop instead of the event loop. Just copy and paste the code in my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.